# SQL 2012: Import DB changes original data scheme

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I'm migrating data from SQL 2008 R2 Servers to SQL 2012. Therefore I'm using SSMS Import Data Task on the SQL 2012 machines.

As a test I copied the data files of one of the DBs, did an "Attach Database" and a schema compare with the latest SQL Server Data Tools.

The diff from the attached vs. the imported-one seems just wrong. 
As an example:

Attached:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DbEventMessages] (
[EventID]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[EntityType]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[ContactId]       INT            NOT NULL,
[Action]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[DateTime]        DATETIME2 (7)  NOT NULL,
[InnoVersionType] ROWVERSION     NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DbDbEventMessages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EventID] ASC)
);
GO
```

Imported:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DbEventMessages] (
[EventID]         INT            NOT NULL,
[EntityType]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[ContactId]       INT            NOT NULL,
[Action]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[DateTime]        DATETIME2 (7)  NOT NULL,
[InnoVersionType] ROWVERSION     NOT NULL
);
GO
```

The imported scheme differs in

- the IDENTITY property on the key column
- the ROWVERSION was changed from NOT NULL to NULL
- the primary key constraint is missing

What is wrong here? Or is it working correctly?
Thanks for any comments..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a backup of the SQL Server 2008 databases and restore it on SQL Server 2012. It is a much faster and reliable approach to migrating a database. Do not attach files between the instances, the SQL Server 2012 will upgrade them to a new format and you will loose the ability to use them again on SQL Server 2008.

As a general advice try to follow the procedures and guidelines, including the pre-migration validation steps from [Upgrade to SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677622.aspx)

Make sure you migrate all login information and SQL Agent jobs relevant for your database(s).

Comment: thanks for your answer! "faster and reliable approach" means that you wouldn't trust SSMS Import Data Task? It's mentioned as a possible migration szenario under your linked article.. "Do not attach files"- Attaching wouldn't change the database compatibility level, would it?

Comment: Attach upgrades the database to the instance version. Once upgraded, there is no downgrade path. If you attached the SQL 2008R2 DBs to a SQL 2102 those are now SQL 2012 files *and you cannot change them back to 2008R2, ever*. Compatibility level is a completely different thing.

Comment: As an aside I highly recommend backup/restore over detach/attach. [See my reasons here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18593/should-i-migrate-data-using-detach-copy-attach-or-through-backup-restore-replay).

Comment: SSMS data migration level is an migration option, I would never consider it though, specially if backup/restore is available as an option. But if I would have to use SSMS I would use the [Copy Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx) wizard, not the Export/Import *Data* wizard.

Comment: Tried it according to your comments + scheme compare each time: Import/Export doesn't seems to work as "expected" for this scenario and results as written in the inital question. Backup/Restore, SSMS Copy DB, Detach/Copy/Attach worked well. Backup/Restore is unquestioned the most secure and reliable way. Thanks for sharing your knowledge

Comment: @Lin-Art Also for keeping them in sync (e.g. assuming you will continue developing on the original server and deploy changes over time to the new server), I recommend a 3rd party tool for this. I use Red-Gate SQL Compare but there are other alternatives I mentioned in a [blog post about re-inventing the wheel](http://bertrandaaron.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/).

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand thanks, used to use open dbdiff (on your list too ;) and my own scripts packed into my app-upgrades. have you already tried the latest SQL Server Data Tools? Nice to handle for any EF developer